# jaydebeapi connection terminates without any exception or error | unable to investigate further

Tags: python-3.x, azure, hive, azure-hdinsight, jaydebeapi

I followed the usage steps as per the example, after the second step of defining "conn" the script terminates and comes back to the command line without raising any errors o warnings or exception.
I am not able to identify what went wrong, has anyone faced this issue with jaydebeapi?

Sharing the libraries/environment details I am using and screenshot.

**Example:**

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver",
... "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:.",
... ["SA", ""],
... "/path/to/hsqldb.jar",) --------my script terminates at this step
curs = conn.cursor()
```

**Environment:**

```
Windows 10 64bit
Python 3.7.4
JayDeBeApi==1.1.1
JPype1==0.6.3
sasl==0.2.1
thrift==0.10.0
thrift-sasl==0.3.0
Jar = hive-jdbc-1.2.1-standalone.jar
```

[image]

Resolution is appreciated.

Comment: Your JPype1 version is pretty old. It got some stability improvements in the last couple of releases. Try upgrading to a newer version. Also there is a newer version of JayDeBeApi available.

Comment: @bastian: after upgrading the libs -  still facing the same issue. if any stack-trace or exception/error/warning gets printed to console; it will be helpful in debugging the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using same (i.e. 64 bit) versions of programms? Reinstallation from python 32 to python 64 helped me with the same problem.